# What is the structure of the hot spot under Hawaii?

Tags: mantle, mantle-plumes, hotspot

The Hawaiian Islands are formed by volcanic activity over a hotspot in the Earth's mantle. What is the shape of this hotspot in the mantle? Is it like a pyramid or a pillar or an upside-down pyramid?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask? Are you asking about the shape of the seafloor around Hawaii or are you asking about the shape of the hot spot in the mantle beneath Hawaii?

Comment: the shape of the hot spot in the mantle beneath Hawaii